# CreateInstance InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, reflection

There are three builds in my .net core application.

Solution.Models.Customer:

```
public class Customer : ICustomer
{           
    public void Get()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message!");
    }
}
```

Solution.Interfaces.ICustomer:

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    void Get();
}
```

Solution.Creator.ContainerCreator:

```
public class ContainerCreator
{
    Assembly _assembly;

    public void Add(Assembly assembly)
    {
        _assembly = assembly;
    }

    public object CreateInstance(Type type)
    {
        object instance;

        var classesInfo = GetClassesInfo();
        //classes Info looks for a match in the assembly with the passed parameter.
        var result = classesInfo.Where(w => w.ClassType.FullName == type.FullName).FirstOrDefault();

        var objectType = result.ClassType;

        instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then, when I create an object with the (*ICustomer*) type, it is **successfully** created, but if I cast to the (*Customer*) type, then an exception occurs - **System.InvalidCastException**.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                "Solution.Models.dll",
                SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(files[0]);

ContainerCreator containerCreator = new ContainerCreator();

containerCreator.Add(asm);
// Success
Customer = (ICustomer)containerCreator.CreateInstance(typeof(Customer));
// System.InvalidCastException
//Customer = (Customer)containerCreator.CreateInstance(typeof(Customer));
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I defeat this exception?

Comment: If Customer and ICustomer are defined in different assemblies: are you sure all the loaded assemblies match? You can check this e.g. in the debugger in the Modules window.

Comment: Your program that is calling CreateInstance knows the `Customer` type already from somewhere (otherwise you could not use this type in your source code there). Most likely the origin of that `Customer` type is not the Solution.Models.dll itself. Thus, you would have two different `Customer` types that are not convertible between each other (one from your program, one from your Solution.Models.dll)

Comment: Since your program already knows the type `Customer` -- it has to, otherwise the complier would complain about not knowing `Customer` when trying to compile `Customer = (ICustomer)containerCreator.CreateInstance(typeof(Customer));` --, why do you go through all the hoopla with `ContainerCreator` and trying to load the assembly instead of just doing `new Customer()`? Your approach, as presented here, doesn't really make much sense...

Comment: Side note: What is this funky weirdness you do with `Directory.GetFiles(...)` there? Wouldn't it be much simpler to do `var dllPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Solution.Models.dll")`?

Comment: First, you should provide the full exception message of the `InvalidCastException`. Secondly, if you can do `typeof(Customer)`, then that class `Customer` is already in scope, so why not do `new Customer()`? If you, just as @elgonzo suggests, have _two_ unrelated classes both called `Customer`, you cannot create one with a reference to the `Type` object of the other, and you also cannot cast an instance of one of them to an interface implemented only by the other class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:I think OP is trying to create some kind of Plugin stuff. If so, there are many custom libraries for that I suggest you can use already implemented stuff, rather than creating the wheel by yourself

This is a pretty common mistake when people first start to play with assemblies during run time. Been there done that :) The problem is that you are using `Assembly.LoadFile` to load your assembly into your app-domain. Without going further into detail, even if you load the same dll using `Assembly.LoadFile`, types defined in the assembly will be treated as differently. Let us say I have assembly A

```
../MyFolder/A.dll
     public class MyType;
     public class MyAnotherType;
     ....

 var aDll = Assembly.LoadFile("A.dll");
 var aDllAgain = Assembly.LoadFile("A.dll");
 var myTypeFromADll =aDll.GetType("MyType");
 var myTypeFromADllAgain = aDllAgain.GetType("MyType");

 //Yes this is of type MyType but since you used LoadFile
 //It is of type MyType from a_dll code base
 var instanceFromADll = Activator.CreateInstance(myTypeFromADll);

 //Yes this is of type MyType but since you used LoadFile
 //It is of type MyType from a_dll_again code base
 var instanceFromADllAgain = Activator.CreateInstance(myTypeFromADllAgain);
```

So you are getting an InvalidCastException because you are trying to cast an instance of type X into type Y.

The solution is simple. You should use `Assemly.Load` method, and somehow if you can not next is `Assembly.LoadFrom`. Unless you know absolutely what you are doing, stay away from `Assembly.LoadFile`.

Here is a very good and detailed explanation. [Best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading)